# cmake download hash missmatch

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I need to build project from github:

https://github.com/andre-schulz/mve

it has these steps in Cmake file:

```
set(ZLIB_FILENAME "zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz")
blablabla
set(ZLIB_URL "https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/${ZLIB_FILENAME}")
blablabla
ExternalProject_Add(zlib
    PREFIX build/zlib
    URL ${ZLIB_URL}
    URL_HASH SHA256=4ff941449631ace0d4d203e3483be9dbc9da454084111f97ea0a2114e19bf066
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=<INSTALL_DIR>
        -DSKIP_INSTALL_FILES:BOOL=ON)
```

the problem is that it can't download files even with good connection (I download files quickly in my browser, I have no proxy). So I get this trash during building:

```
3>    does not match expected value
3>      expected: 'c572c30a4e64689c342ba1624130ac98936d7af90c3103f9ce12b8a0c5736764'
3>        actual: '7a07d3f7cca5c0b38ca811984ef8da536da32932d68c1a6cce33ec2462b930bf'
3>  -- Hash mismatch, removing...
3>  -- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #2) ...
2>  -- Using src='https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz'
2>  -- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #3) ...
3>  -- Using src='https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/glew/glew/2.0.0/glew-2.0.0.tgz'
2>  -- Using src='https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz'
2>  -- Retry after 15 seconds (attempt #4) ...
3>  -- [download 100% complete]
3>  -- verifying file...
3>         file='C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz'
3>  -- SHA256 hash of
3>      C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz
3>    does not match expected value
3>      expected: 'c572c30a4e64689c342ba1624130ac98936d7af90c3103f9ce12b8a0c5736764'
3>        actual: '7a07d3f7cca5c0b38ca811984ef8da536da32932d68c1a6cce33ec2462b930bf'
3>  -- Hash mismatch, removing...
3>  -- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #3) ...
3>  -- Using src='https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/glew/glew/2.0.0/glew-2.0.0.tgz'
3>  -- [download 100% complete]
3>  -- verifying file...
3>         file='C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz'
3>  -- SHA256 hash of
3>      C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz
3>    does not match expected value
3>      expected: 'c572c30a4e64689c342ba1624130ac98936d7af90c3103f9ce12b8a0c5736764'
3>        actual: '7a07d3f7cca5c0b38ca811984ef8da536da32932d68c1a6cce33ec2462b930bf'
3>  -- Hash mismatch, removing...
3>  -- Retry after 15 seconds (attempt #4) ...
2>  -- Using src='https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz'
3>  -- Using src='https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/glew/glew/2.0.0/glew-2.0.0.tgz'
2>  -- Retry after 60 seconds (attempt #5) ...
3>  -- [download 100% complete]
3>  -- verifying file...
3>         file='C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz'
3>  -- SHA256 hash of
3>      C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz
3>    does not match expected value
3>      expected: 'c572c30a4e64689c342ba1624130ac98936d7af90c3103f9ce12b8a0c5736764'
3>        actual: '7a07d3f7cca5c0b38ca811984ef8da536da32932d68c1a6cce33ec2462b930bf'
3>  -- Hash mismatch, removing...
```

What might be the rootcause of this and how can I download files manually? Is it possible to avoid redownloading files?

Comment: `What might be the rootcause of this?` - Wrong hash or the file under link was changed since given hash value has been obtained. BTW, "expected" value of the hash differs from one in the command. Are you sure that exactly given command causes this? You may remove *URL_HASH* option with parameter, so the file's hash won't be checked.

Comment: I've checked, sometimes downloaded file is empty and then its deleted. may be this is a rootcause?

Comment: I am unsure, but it could be a problem with supporting https protocol by CMake. Which CMake version do you use? Do you build CMake by yourself, or got prebuilt one (for Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

To download the file manually, you can download the file once and put it in the place where CMake expects it. Here it seems `C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/kinnekt/git/mve-win/mve/3rdparty/build/glew/src/glew-2.0.0.tgz`.

As long as the hash matches, CMake will not reattempt a download.